# How do i check my file (file is : a text file that am storing all the configuration)is empty or not in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying following function to check file data exist or not if not exist it will display validation message on console.

```js
$("#eventDelete").click(function() {
   const fs = require('fs')

   fs.readFile('safeList.txt', (err, data) => {
       if (err) throw err;
       alert(data);
       if (data == null) {
         $('#event_responseErr').html("no records to delete.");
         return false;
       }
     }
   });
```

Comment: `fs.readFile` is node.js code that runs server side. You can't use it with jquery on the browser

Comment: Is this node or in the browser?

Comment: @Phix it is browser

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this or see this : `https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/filereader+javascript+example`

```
<html> 

 
<head> 
    <title>Read Text File</title> 
</head> 
  
<body> 
    <input type="file" name="inputfile"
            id="inputfile"> 
    <br> 
   
    <pre id="output"></pre> 
      
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        document.getElementById('inputfile') 
            .addEventListener('change', function() { 
              
            var fr=new FileReader(); 
            fr.onload=function(){ 
            if(fr.result){
            alert('Data Found');
            }else{
             alert('No Data Found');
            }
            //    document.getElementById('output') 
                     //   .textContent=fr.result; 
            } 
              fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);
           
        }) 
    </script> 
</body> 
  
</html>
```